# Get the "annote" field of a .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I have BibTeX entries that look like this:

```
@inproceedings{Defraene2010,
annote = {This is a very nice paper.I will say more about it later},
author = {Defraene, Bruno and van Waterschoot, Toon and Ferreau, Hans Joachim and Diehl, Moritz and Moonen, Marc and Waterschoot, Toon Van},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 18th European Signal Processing Conference (EUSIPCO ’10), Aalborg, Denmark, Aug. 2010},
keywords = {clipping},
title = {{Perception-based clipping of audio signals}},
volume = {006},
year = {2010}
}
```

How can I get the content of the "annote" field in my LaTeX document?

I am looking for something like this in the LaTeX file:

```
\cite{Defraene2010}: \citexxx[annote]{Defraene2010}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution using the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package. (Note that `biblatex` treats the field `annote` as an alias for `annotation`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\newcommand*{\annotecite}[1]{(\citefield{#1}{annotation}) \autocite{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Defraene2010,
  annote = {This is a very nice paper. I will say more about it later},
  author = {Defraene, Bruno and van Waterschoot, Toon and Ferreau, Hans Joachim and Diehl, Moritz and Moonen, Marc and Waterschoot, Toon Van},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 18th European Signal Processing Conference (EUSIPCO 10), Aalborg, Denmark, Aug. 2010},
  keywords = {clipping},
  title = {Perception-based clipping of audio signals},
  volume = {006},
  year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \annotecite{Defraene2010}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```