# Insert the content of the annote field using new \citexxx and \newcommand

Tags: bibtex

I am new to TeX (MacTeX 2011, with XeLaTeX and BibDesk / BibTeX). In parts I found this answer to my question - but it is not what I want : [Get the "annote" field of a .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/get-the-annote-field-of-a-bibtex-file)

I look for a way to insert the content of my annote field in direct quotes.

1. I like to have a new command like `\annotecite`.
2. it should insert the content of the `annote` filed in the text.
3. it should not modify the existing citations, like change the counts of citations and so on.
4. it should not use `biblatex`, `jurabib` and so on - the citation styles are ok as they are and I want only to insert the content of the field (also if I change the style).

Comment: This is quite tough specification I think. `bibtex` knows only to produce the `.bbl` file from your `.bib` file, and you can hardly get such structure in the `.bbl` file. I think that best option is to go along with `biblatex`, because it will likely be easier to switch the bibliography engine than to try to tweak `bibtex` to do what you want.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer. I have tried apacite with apacann and apacannx. Then I have the content from the annote field inside the bibliography (now I know it is basically possible but don´t know how to access the content inside the text using a own \cite command). Where are the definitions of the \cite and what it should do are stored ? Is it a solution to create a own style using tex makebst to get this to work ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Because `biblatex` and its `\citefield` command allows easy access to the data of the `.bib` file, your best bet in my opinion is to switch to `biblatex` and tweak an existing style so as to meet your needs.

Answer (score 4):

My `usebib` package can be helpful:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{monster,
author={von Frankenstein, Victor},
title={How I did it},
journal={J. Applied Physiology},
year={1931},
annote={Be very careful when doing like this},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{annote}
\bibinput{mybib}

\begin{document}
This is the annote field in the entry:
``\usebibentry{monster}{annote}''
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** The `filecontents` environment is just to produce a suitable bibliography file for the example. I realized that the package documentation is wrong (it has different macro names than those really to be used); a fix is on its way to CTAN. The current documentation has `\usebibdata` and `\usebibdataurl`, while the correct commands are `\usebibentry` and `\usebibentryurl`.